# ¿Por qué aparece esto en la terminal de VSCode? ¿Cómo logro que no tome tanto tiempo en ejecutar el código?

Tags: vscode, powershell

Les comento mi situación.

Me encuentro programando en Java en Vscode. Resulta que el código demora un tiempo considerable en ejecutarse, cuando pensaría debería ser casi instantáneo.
Me aparece el mensaje: "Loading personal and system profiles took Xms". No sé que significa y no sé si tendrá que ver con que el terminal demoré en ejecutar el código.

¿Saben por qué sucede esto y cómo arreglarlo? Sería como acelerar el tiempo de respuesta del terminal de Vscode o algo así. ¡Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pues actualizaste PowerShell como te dice ahí?

Comment: Síp, actualizar ya lo he intentando. La acabo de descargar y sigue apareciendo el mensaje y tomando algo de tiempo en ejecutar el código. :'c

Comment: Si actualizaste asegúrate de cerrar completamente VS Code (cierra todo en el Administrador de Tareas), reiniciar también debería de funcionar, o checa que pasa si ejecutas el proyecto en Powershell fuera de VS Code.

Comment: Cuando abro Powershell, de por sí, el mismo programa demora en ejecutarse, también aparece el mensaje. :'c

Comment: Qué pasa si utilizas el CMD? No tienes una actualización de Windows pendientes? Probaste utilizando la app Terminal?

Comment: Hola, si, actualicé PowerShell y ahora se ejecuta el código inmediatamente. Era ese el problema. ¡Muchas gracias! :')